# How to access a registered I2C device in the linux kernel from userspace

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, i2c, userspace

I want to be able to modify registers in a I2C slave device.
The device has a driver in the kernel, and the driver registers an I2C client with the address of it.

The driver is very basic and does output all the device functionality.
I want to access the registers from user space, but when I try to access it with I2C-dev, I get the error - Device or resource busy.

I don't want to add functionality to the driver, and I prefer to write a user space application to modify the device registers.

How can use I2C-dev to modify the registers in such a case?

Answer (score 1):

So after investigating the I2C-dev I managed to overcome the problem. I noticed the flag I2C_SLAVE_FORCE inside the ioctl function. With the flag set, the function ignores if the I2C address is already registered.